# how to block application installation

Tags: android-activity, android-install-apk, android-package-managers

I want to block application installation in android.The user downloads the app from android market.If the user tries to install the application the application should not get
install.I have to create an app or i should modify the android middleware according to this. How i can block the application installation.

Comment: I am also stuck there, i have try to by using broadcast receiver and intent filter but not succeeded